# Asymptotics: justification for abusing Laplace's method

Tags: asymptotics, laplace-method

[Laplace's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace%27s_method) allows to get an asympotic approximation, for $N\to \infty$, of integrals of the form

$$ \int e ^{N f(x)}dx $$

I plead guilty of abusing several times (eg: [exhibit 1](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/78167/312) and [exhibit 2](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2229855/312)) of the method, by using a function in the exponent that actually depends also on $N$, say $f(x,N)$.

That's obviously illegal, and, in general, will produce nonsense. But in the above examples it worked nicely for me.

I guess there should be some justification, or some known recipe for extending Laplace's method for these scenarios - perhaps imposing some restriction on $f(x,N)$ - probably that it varies "slowly" (or "asymptotically almost constant") with $N$.

Can someone devise such extension, or provide some reference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The power of the Laplace method is that it really is much more than a single theorem, and the statements on the wiki page page are specializations of the general method.

In his book *Asymptotic Methods in Analysis*, N. G. de Bruijn works out several examples in full detail which aren't of the usual $\int f e^{Ng}$ form. See, in particular, chapter 6.

From the preface of the book:

> The reader will not find anything like a general theory in this book. Many asymptotic methods are very flexible, and in such cases it is not possible to formulate a single theorem covering all applications. Any attempt at generalization would actually result in a restriction.

I've fully worked out (relatively tame) examples on Math.SE [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1052676/5531) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/197602/5531) too.