# Rigorous proofs of Laplace integral approximation with $\lambda$-dependent exponent

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, reference-request, asymptotics, approximation

I am looking for a rigorous, textbook-style proof of the Laplace approximation of general exponential integrals of the form
$$
\int e^{\lambda h(\lambda,t)}g(\lambda,t)\,dt
\quad\text{as}\quad
\lambda\to\infty.
\tag{*}
$$

Every treatment I have found assumes that $h(t)$ does not depend on $\lambda$. Frustratingly, Miller's "Applied Asymptotic Analysis" introduces the subject using the general integral $(*)$, but only proves results for $h(t)$.

(There are many more resources and lecture notes online, e.g. [these notes](http://majdalani.eng.auburn.edu/courses/06_perturbations_2/Lecture_on_the_Laplace_Method.pdf), but they only treat $h(t)$ as well.)

Comment: You may have a look at F. W. J. Olver's book *Asymptotics and Special Functions*. Especially, Chapter 9, Sections 2 and 4.

Comment: Related https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2234358/asymptotics-justification-for-abusing-laplaces-method